# MySql + MyBatis in multithread application

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, mybatis

Good morning. I have a multithreaded application that accesses in reading writing to a DB mySql . Use myBatis . For session management it wrote the following class:

```java
public class ConnectionMySQL {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionMySQL.class);

    private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    private ConnectionMySQL() {
    }

    static {
        try {
            String resource = "com/application/dao/config/mybatis-config.xml";
            InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
            sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("Impossibile avviare la connessione sul DB", e);
        }
    }

    public static SqlSessionFactory getSession() {
        return sqlSessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Whenever I run a query I run these operations :

```java
public void start() {
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+" ***** Start ****");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SqlSession sessione = ConnectionMySQL.getSession().openSession();
    try {
        ..........
        ..........
    }catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.warn("Impossibile inviare messaggio di notifica");
    }finally {
        sessione.close();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Numero thread :"+numeroThread+" - Tempo di esecuzione "+ (end - start) +" ms");

    }

}
```

I am not very experienced in MySQL and myBatis . I wanted to know if this is the proper way to handle the multi thread with myBatis. Thank's.

Answer (score 4):

`SqlSessionFactory` is thread safe. Just pass it around. You are safe to use it.

`SqlSession` is **not** thread safe and should be used only in **method scope**.

I would recommend the [DAO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) to structure your database code:

```
public MyPojo select(int primaryKey) {
    try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
        MyPojoMapper mapper = session.getMapper(MyPojoMapper.class);
        return mapper.select(primaryKey);
    }
}
```